# In KSH, how would you get the FIRST Parent ID when you're two processes in?

Tags: output, echo, ksh, pid

Suppose I have three fairly simple scripts.

`script1` ->runs-> `script2` ->runs-> `script3`.

and I want script3 to be able to do the following:

`echo "the PID of script1 is $PPID";`

this however, consistently outputs the PID of `script2`. Is there any way to work this so that it will output the PID of script1?

Answer (score 0):

You can get pid of the parent of `$PPID` using `$(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=)`

Then in order to print the pid of the parent of the parent of script3 you can use :

```
echo "the PID of script1 is $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=)"
```

An alternative using `procfs` :

```
echo "the PID of script1 is $(cat /proc/$PPID/stat | cut -d ' ' -f4)"
```

Comment: this works up to -o now,
now ps is complaining that there are too many arguments

Comment: I add a alternative using procfs, if it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one on your "c" script:

```
echo "the PID of script1 is $(ps -hoppid $PPID | sed 's/ //g')"
```

You are requesting the ps command to tell you the parent pid of your shell's parent pid without heading, then you are removing spaces from returned output.